# Remote MySQL Connect with desktop application using static ip

Tags: java, mysql, static, ip, remote-access

For our university project we are developing java application and all the data goes to Online Mysql database. but the problem is that hosting provider only let us to connect with mysql with specific IP address. but we have dynamic ip. we have to add our computer IP address in server before we connect. but problem is our client is moving and he might use USB dongle or WIFI hotspot.so ip is going to change. how are we going to use Static IP to computer?
how real world software developers overcome this problem?

Comment: You mean ip address is going to change?

Comment: yes, when client move around with software ip going to change,. then he cant access mysql with remote

Comment: Do you host/administer that online mysql server? You can configure VPN on clients and allow connections for VPN address pool, you can use a proxy as Ankit suggested or you can open your mysql to the whole world.